# Como usar HTML Agility pack?

Tags: c#, .net

Como Usar o HTML Agility Pack meu projeto no Visual Studio em C#, pois tenho uma tabela extraída por um objeto *webbrowsers*, mais quando vou dar uns *splits* nele ele fica como uma array de quase 700 índices, eu gostaria de achar o elementos que eu quero mais facilmente,

```
 private void timer_loteca_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //loteca
        WebBrowser clienteloteca = new WebBrowser();

        clienteloteca.Navigate("http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/loterias/loteca/loteca_pesquisa_new.asp");

        clienteloteca.Navigated += clienteloteca_Navigated;

        timer_federal.Enabled = false;


    }

    void clienteloteca_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

            var s = (WebBrowser)sender; ;
            string acumulou = string.Empty;

            var tabela = s.Document.Body.InnerHtml;

            string[] lala = tabela.Split('|');

            string[] line22 = Regex.Split(lala[3], "<table" );

            string line24 = line22[0].Replace("\r\n","");
            string[] line23 = Regex.Split(line24, "</TD>");

            var megasena = s.Document.Body.InnerText;


            string megasena1 = megasena;

            string[] lines = megasena1.Split('|');

            string[] line20 = Regex.Split(lines[3], "\r\n");

            string[] line30 = Regex.Split(lines[4], "\r\n");

            string res1 = line20[1].ToString().Substring(0,1);
            string res2 = line20[1].ToString().Substring(1);
            string res3 = line20[5].ToString().Substring(0, 1);
            string res4 = line20[5].ToString().Substring(1);
            string res5 = line20[9].ToString().Substring(0, 1);
            string res6 = line20[9].ToString().Substring(1);
            string res7 = line20[13].ToString().Substring(0, 1);
            string res8 = line20[13].ToString().Substring(1);
            string res9 = line20[17].ToString().Substring(0, 1);
            string res10 = line20[17].ToString().Substring(1);
            string res11 = line20[21].ToString().Substring(0, 1);
            string res12 = line20[21].ToString().Substring(1);
            string res13 = line20[25].ToString().Substring(0, 1);
            string res14 = line20[25].ToString().Substring(1);
            string res15 = line20[29].ToString().Substring(0, 1);
            string res16 = line20[29].ToString().Substring(1);
            string res17 = line20[33].ToString().Substring(0, 1);
            string res18 = line20[33].ToString().Substring(1);
}
```

Comment: Você terá de dar mais detalhes, pois a sua pergunta está muito vaga.

Comment: Você já incluiu o HtmlAgilityPack no projeto? Quais são os elementos que você deseja obter? Qual é a dificuldade que você está tendo com a biblioteca?

Comment: então eu instalei o pack, esta na referencia do meu projeto tudo normal, li a documentação dele mais não entendi como eu consigo pegar os valores de dentro da tabela em questão.

Comment: Qual a plataforma para que estás a desenvolver? Podes acrescentar algum código de exemplo extremamente simples que ilustre o que pretendes?

Comment: estou desenvolvendo em c# windows form no visual studio,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não conheço o site do qual você está tentando fazer parse, porém vejo alguns erros na sua concepção do código:

- Primeiramente, não é necessário usar a classe `WebBrowser`... essa classe representa um controle gráfico para ser usado em uma janela. Ao invés disso, use a classe `WebClient` para fazer download da página.
- Segundo, você não precisa usar regex nem split para fazer parse da página... para isso serve o HtmlAgilityPack.

Criei um exemplo de como ficaria o seu código usando essa biblioteca:

```
//loteca
var client = new WebClient();

client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] =
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
    +"Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
client.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip";

var html = client.DownloadString(
    "http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/loterias/loteca/loteca_pesquisa_new.asp");

var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

// pegando uma lista com as tabelas da página
var todasAsTabelas = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("table");
```

Eu pessoalmente não tenho acesso a este site do meu local de trabalho, portanto não pude testar... mas posso fazer um exemplo com algum outro site sem ser *www1.caixa.gov.br* como exemplo se for preciso.

Comment: entao eu testei e não estava fazendo o download html, porem consegui outro jeito de pegar e ja posto aqui na pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Bom consegui pegar os valores na tabela desse jeito

```
private void timer_loteca_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //loteca

        WebBrowser clienteloteca = new WebBrowser();

        if (timer_loteca.Enabled == true)
        {
            clienteloteca.Navigate("http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/loterias/loteca/loteca_pesquisa_new.asp");
            timer_loteca.Enabled = false;
        }

        /*
        //Check if page is fully loaded or not
        while (clienteloteca.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();

        }*/



            //Action to be taken on page loading completion




             clienteloteca.DocumentCompleted += clienteloteca_DocumentCompleted;



    }



public class JogosLoteca {
        public String Jogo { get; set; }            
        public String Time1 { get; set; }
        public String Resultado1 { get; set; }
        public String Time2 { get; set; }
        public String Resultado2 { get; set; }
        public String Data { get; set; }
    }

    public class ganhadoresloteca
    {
        public String faixa { get; set; }
        public String num_ganhadores { get; set; }
        public String val_premio { get; set; }

    }


clienteloteca_DocumentCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
            var s = (WebBrowser)sender; ;
            string acumulou = string.Empty;

            //var tabela = s.Document.Body.InnerHtml;

            var mDocument = s.Document;
            var TabelaDeJogosLoteca = mDocument.GetElementById("tabela_jogo_loteca");
            List<JogosLoteca> jogos = new List<JogosLoteca>();


            for (var i = 0; i < TabelaDeJogosLoteca.Children[1].Children.Count; i++)
            {

                HtmlElement trElement = TabelaDeJogosLoteca.Children[1].Children[i];
                var coluna1 = trElement.Children[0].InnerText;
                var coluna2 = trElement.Children[1].InnerText;
                var coluna3 = trElement.Children[2].InnerText;
                var coluna4 = trElement.Children[3].InnerText;
                var coluna5 = trElement.Children[4].InnerText;
                var coluna6 = trElement.Children[5].InnerText;
                var coluna7 = trElement.Children[6].InnerText;
                jogos.Add(new JogosLoteca
                {

                    Jogo = coluna1,
                    Resultado1 = coluna2,
                    Time1 = coluna3,
                    Time2 = coluna5,
                    Resultado2 = coluna6,
                    Data = coluna7


                });
            }}
```

Mas não foi usado o html agility pack